# OpenCV colour mixing

Tags: opencv

I have a multiple colour tracking application using OpenCV. I want to check that if the green image touches the red image, it will produce a yellow spot. 
Where moments a are the green spatial moments and r are for red spatial moments.

```
if //(lastXR==lastA || lastYR==lastB  || posXR==posA || posYR==posB){
  ( moment10a ==moment10r || moment01a ==moment01r || arear==areaa ){

  cvCircle(imgScribble, cvPoint(moment01r,moment01a), 5, cvScalar(0,255,255),-1, CV_AA);
 }
```

This ends up giving me a yellow dot at the corner of the screen but not when the 2 colours meet. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Change || to &&. And it's better to use inequality,than the strict ==.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by inequality

Comment: You can change A==something to A>A_lo_boundary && A<A_high_boundary its very hard to catch precise coincidence of variables. Lo and high boundaries usually differs by small value.